# how do i display data i inserted individually in different layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

i have a main page with 2 buttons 'save' & 'search'. when 'save' button is clicked it would open the layout '**DATA**' for inserting data such as name, country, city, category, comment. OnClickSave the data would be saved. when the 'search' button is clicked it would open the layout countries.the layout would display data key in countries than selecting from the list it would open the city layout that is save under the country and so on. how do i do so??

Comment: use <include> tag to include your layout in another layout.

Answer (score 0):

I will just write steps here.

Main activity:

1. On Save button Click : Open a new activity with form. Save the data to database.
2. On Search button Click: You can open a new activity with listview in it. That listview can contain every country inside database table. On click, you can go to other activity which will fetch the country details, and display them.

If you have any doubt, then please ask.

Comment: @gene It will be too big a code.. If u are stuck in middle, just put your code. So I will try to help you.

Comment: ok... i am a thousand years late!! but really appreciate your help!! I probably flunked the assignment. Hope you will see my reply to receive my thanks!